# How to set folder permission to read only in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a ready only folder in sdcard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838168/create-a-ready-only-folder-in-sdcard-in-android)

I am making an application in android and I want to make a ready only folder in sdcard. How can we set this permission. If possible please provide me a valid link.

Please help me. I am suck

Thanks in advance.